# slide show images and webpage loading time

Tags: jquery, slideshow, page-load-time

I am going to ask something strange question, so not sure how many down votes will get for this question:(

I created a PHP website with sideshow ([jQuery Immersive Slider](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/immersive_slider_demo.html)) in homepage. Initially everything was working well. But as per my client' request i added an additional frame for slideshow images. So i put frame image in `<img src="frame.jpg"/>` and use slider images as background.

And the result is, it will take longer time (about 15-20 sec more than webpage) for image loading.If i go to the website, first 15-20 sec i can see the images are scattered around,after that become fine. But this is not good:( Anybody have any idea about how can i reduce the loading time? or is there any way to load the page and the slideshow together(i mean is there any way to set loading time for webpage)?

Comment: have you optimized the images? and the js? Use http://www.tinypng.com if you don't have photoshop for pic compression - its really good and they do png and jpg, and http://refresh-sf.com/ for css and js compressions

Comment: You can compare performance before and after, using pagespeed insights https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/